# Altering the tensorflow graph and resuming training

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to load the pretrained weights of [MCnet model](https://github.com/rubenvillegas/iclr2017mcnet) and resume training. The pretrained model provided here is trained with parameters `K=4, T=7`. But, I want a model with parameters `K=4,T=1`. Instead of starting training from scratch, I want to load the weights from this pretrained model. But since the graph has changed, I'm unable to load the pretrained model.

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Restoring from checkpoint failed. This is most likely due to a mismatch between the current graph and the graph from the checkpoint. Please ensure that you have not altered the graph expected based on the checkpoint. Original error:

Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [5,5,15,64] rhs shape= [5,5,33,64]
     [[node save/Assign_13 (defined at /media/nagabhushan/Data02/SNB/IISc/Research/04_Gaming_Video_Prediction/Workspace/VideoPrediction/Literature/01_MCnet/src/snb/mcnet.py:108) ]]
```

Is it possible to load the pretrained model with the new graph?

**What I have tried**:
Previously, I wanted to port the pretrained model from on older version of tensorflow to a newer one. I got [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57818431/3337089) in SO which helped me port the model. The idea is to create the new graph and load variables existing in new graph from the saved one.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    _ = MCNET(image_size=[240, 320], batch_size=8, K=4, T=1, c_dim=3, checkpoint_dir=None, is_train=True)
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run(session=sess)

    ckpt_vars = tf.train.list_variables(model_path.as_posix())
    ass_ops = []
    for dst_var in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES):
        for (ckpt_var, ckpt_shape) in ckpt_vars:
            if dst_var.name.split(":")[0] == ckpt_var and dst_var.shape == ckpt_shape:
                value = tf.train.load_variable(model_path.as_posix(), ckpt_var)
                ass_ops.append(tf.assign(dst_var, value))

    # Assign the variables
    sess.run(ass_ops)
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    saver.save(sess, save_path.as_posix())
```

I tried the same here and it worked, meaning I got a new trained model for `K=4,T=1`. But I'm not sure if it is valid! I mean, will the weights make sense? Is this the right way to do it?

**Info about the Model**:
MCnet is a model used for video prediction i.e. given `K` past frames, it can predict the next `T` frames.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You can load the weights from the original model in the shape they come and possibly add zeros or ones (or some weight initializer) to fill the rest.

Comment: It's the other way round here. My new model has lesser parameters (I guess). Since the model uses LSTMs, I'm not sure if throwing away some weights would be okay or would it affect me negatively.

Comment: Oh I see, is it possible for you to list the weight matrices? So that (if possible) one can figure out what weights to drop meaningfully

Comment: You mean to list the parameters here? I guess there will be too many.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MCnet model has a generator and a discriminator. Generator is LSTM based and hence there is no problem in loading of the weights by varying the number of timesteps `T`. However the discriminator, as they've coded it, is convolutional. To apply convolutional layers on video, they are concatenating the frames in channel dimension. With `K=4,T=7`, you get a video of length `11` with `3` channels. When you concatenate them along channel dimension, you get an image with `33` channels. When they define discriminator, they define the first layer of discriminator to have `33` input channels and hence the weights have similar dimension. But with `K=4,T=1`, video length is `5` and the final image has `15` channels and so the weights would have 15 channels. This is the mismatch error you're observing. To fix this, you can pick weights from the first 15 channels only (**for lack of a better way I can think of**). Code below:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    _ = MCNET(image_size=[240, 320], batch_size=8, K=4, T=1, c_dim=3, checkpoint_dir=None, is_train=True)
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run(session=sess)

    ckpt_vars = tf.train.list_variables(model_path.as_posix())
    ass_ops = []
    for dst_var in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES):
        for (ckpt_var, ckpt_shape) in ckpt_vars:
            if dst_var.name.split(":")[0] == ckpt_var:
                if dst_var.shape == ckpt_shape:
                    value = tf.train.load_variable(model_path.as_posix(), ckpt_var)
                    ass_ops.append(tf.assign(dst_var, value))
                else:
                    value = tf.train.load_variable(model_path.as_posix(), ckpt_var)
                    if dst_var.shape[2] <= value.shape[2]:
                        adjusted_value = value[:, :, :dst_var.shape[2]]
                    else:
                        adjusted_value = numpy.random.random(dst_var.shape)
                        adjusted_value[:, :, :value.shape[2], ...] = value
                    ass_ops.append(tf.assign(dst_var, adjusted_value))

    # Assign the variables
    sess.run(ass_ops)
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    saver.save(sess, save_path.as_posix())
```